# Python Pandas Truncate a column to a specific length without cutting the last word

Tags: python, pandas, truncate, maxlength

I try to reduce the length of a column to 50  and I use this lambda fct:

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: x[:50])
```

It is working just fine excepting the fact that its cutting the last word, I need a solution that will remove that last word even if the length will decrease with a few characters.

Thank you for any advice on this

Comment: You want the first 50 characters plus the last word, the first characters plus the last word 50 characters in total, or the first 50 characters and remove the last word from it? Can you please clarify this point?

Comment: I want to have a max of 50 characters on each row from the column, the first words should remain. Im aware that may be situations when ill have under 50 if some final words are removed but it's ok. However, for the situations when row len is already 50 or under, I dont wanna modify them, I want formula to apply only on row with length > 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truncate to up to length `50` characters and cut off the last word:

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[:50].split(' ')[:-1]) if len(x) > 50 else x)
```

Note that going the other way around (first cutting off and only then truncating) may and will result in half-words at the end of the sentence.

How does the lambda expression work?

1. It is given `x`, a current sentence to work on
2. It checks if sentence length is more than 50 chars 
   2.1. If it is, it first truncates to 50 chars then it removes the last word 
   2.2. Else, the sentence is less than 50 chars, the sentence remains intact

Comment: thanks so much! one last question here, is there a condition I can make for situations when I already have len under 50? Because it is deleting the last word from there also and I dont want this like IF the len is < 50 then this [:-1] should not apply, any way can be integrated in your solution?

Comment: Many thanks! I dare to ask, being about lambda expression again, do you have any idea how I can convert this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807411/lemmatize-an-entire-column-using-lambda-function  ?

Comment: @Isa Answered you there :)